# What am I messing in this query

Tags: sql, sqlite, delphi

Database is SQLite.The query is :

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UNIQuery1.Close;
  UNIQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  UNIQuery1.First;
  UNIQuery1.SQL.Text:='SELECT * FROM TEMP2 WHERE DATE=:F1 AND NAME=:F2';
  UNIQuery1.Params.ParamByName('F1').Value:=UNITable1.FieldByName('DATE').Value;
  UNIQuery1.Params.ParamByName('F2').Value:=UNITable1.FieldByName('USER').Value;
  if UNIQuery1.EOF then 
  begin
    UNIQuery1.Close;
    UNIQuery1.SQL.Clear;
    UNIQuery1.SQL.Text:='INSERT INTO TEMP2 (select from TEMP1)';
    UNIQuery1.ExecSQL;
    UNITable2.Refresh;
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('Record already exists !');
end;
```

[image]

I am trying to prevent the insertion of duplicate records.

Comment: It looks like you are closing your query (`UNIQuery1.Close;`) before you are executing it (`UNIQuery1.ExecSQL;`) ?

Comment: You have to open dataset (perform select) by UNIQuery1.Open before you can check EOF

Comment: Don't extend your question to another one. Ask another question! But the answer is: "Your fieldname is `USER` instead of `NAME`"

Comment: yes rufo,sorry I messed up....

Comment: How is Temp1 and Temp2 Filled?

Comment: SO is **not** a blog or diary. Please ask a question and only edit the question to add more details to that question, but don't turn it into a completely other question. For that you must start a new question. I have rolled back all your edits, that changed the starting question.

Comment: @SirRufo, as you can see from my original post, the issue was "I am trying to prevent the insertion of duplicate records." and that the query was not working properly.Solved some issues thanks to your post but the main issue remains. How to make this query work.  You can leave the question as it is but the one edited was more clear.

Comment: You did not ask any question (except that messing in title) and only show an exception dialog. You have to put more effort in your future questions. Also you should avoid to ask more than one question inside a question, otherwise it could be too broad to answer

Comment: I will ask another question then...ok....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just guess that your question is

> Why am I getting this exception?

---

You must not scroll inside the dataset when it is closed.

```pascal
UNIQuery1.Close;
UNIQuery1.SQL.Clear;
UNIQuery1.First; // <-- causes the exception
```

And there is no need at all to go to the first entry inside an **closed** dataset.

So to change the query you should have to *close*, *change the statement* and *open* it.

```pascal
UNIQuery1.Close;
UNIQuery1.SQL.Clear;

UNIQuery1.SQL.Text:='SELECT * FROM TEMP2 WHERE DATE=:F1 AND USER=:F2';
UNIQuery1.Params.ParamByName('F1').Value:=UNITable1.FieldByName('DATE').Value;
UNIQuery1.Params.ParamByName('F2').Value:=UNITable1.FieldByName('USER').Value;

UNIQuery1.Open;
```